# Is it possible to match "ab", "ba" and "ba" in "aba" with single regex?

Tags: regex

I have below text:

```
XXX ab YYY
XXX ba ab YYY
XXX aba YYY
```

What is the single regex to match "ab", "ba" and "ba"? I tried

```
/(?=a)(ba)|ab|ba/ig
```

but it matches `ab` in third line. Here I want "ba" over "ab".

I can get the expected result with multiple regexs. I am looking for a single regex solution.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for word boundaries `\b(?:ab|ba)\b`, or anchors: `^(?:ab|ba)$`..

Comment: How about this: `ab(?!a)|ba`?

Comment: @PetSerAl 's solution works perfect for this! Thanks you

Comment: So now the expected result is `ab` , `ba`, `ba`  ?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to satisfy your examples is to match the final two instances of `a` or `b` in each word:

```
/[ab]{2}\b/
```

Since the intent of your question seems to involve matching patterns other than `ab` and `ba`, this solution is possibly more generalizable:

```
/ab(?!a)|ba/
```

Comment: Ah I use simplified sample. all of those to be matched instances can be in single line and I am doing global match here.

Comment: Then @JoshCrozier's comment is correct; match word boundaries using `\b`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want those literal characters in that literal text: `/(ba)|^ab/g` -- see it working here @ [regular expression 101](https://regex101.com/r/bW3tS6/1)

Comment: @Reddy - 100MB baby!

Comment: Now the question has changed and our answers fail...boo

Answer (score 1):

This must work `(ba)|^ab` . you can check the logic here http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression works for your question.

```
re.findall('(\S*ab\S.*) (ab\S*) (ba\S*)', fileName)
```

The first paranthesis will help you extract string matching ab and followed by a word, like example abort. And the next two paranthesis will help you to get the required answer you need. ab, ba all in single regex.